# Can I type Korean using fcitx under Linux mint 17.2 Cinnamon?

Tags: linux-mint, input-method, fcitx

Can I type Korean using Linux mint 17.2 Cinnamon using `fcitx`?

I have check several post, which told me that I can use iBus to type Korean. But I am using `fcitx` to type other Language like Chinese. If I change my type method to iBus, I cannot type Chinese.

I checked [this post](http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=132951), there is a solution that said that I can install following package to type Korean.

- General packages for Cinnamon:

  ```
  fcitx fcitx-ui-classic fcitx-config-gtk fcitx-frontend-gtk3
  ```
- Specific package for Korean:

  ```
  fcitx-hangul
  ```

However after I installed this package, configure `fcitx`, logout and login, I cannot add Korean type method to `fcitx`.

Answer (score 0):

First install `fcitx-hangul`, and in `fcitx` configuration add "Hangul". Then I can switch input method to Hangul and type Korean.

Remember to **uncheck** *Only Show Current Language* when you add input method in `fcitx` configuration.